# Is it possible to create a http module without making an entry into the web.config or GAC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, gac, httpmodule

The title is my question at this point.  Is it possible to create an http module without making an entry into the web.config or GAC?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime).

[Programmatically register HttpModules at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime)