# Handling application-wide events without Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

My project has no "global.asax" for various reasons and I can't change that (it's a component). Also, I have no access to web.config, so an httpModule is also not an option.

**Is there a way to handle application-wide events**, like "BeginRequest" in this case?

I tried this and it didn't work, can someone explain why? Seems like a bug:

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.BeginRequest += MyStaticMethod;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Event handlers can only be bound to `HttpApplication` events during `IHttpModule` initialization and you're trying to add it somewhere in the `Page_Init`(my assumption).

So you need to register a http module with desired event handlers dynamically. If you're under .NET 4 there is a good news for you - there is `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` attribute (a reference: [Three Hidden Extensibility Gems in ASP.NET 4](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx)):

> This new attribute allows you to have
>   code run way early in the ASP.NET
>   pipeline as an application starts up.
>   I mean way early, even before
>   `Application_Start`.

So the things left are pretty simple: you need to create your own http module with event handlers you want, module initializer and attribute to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file . Here is a module example:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

To register module dynamically you could use [`DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.infrastructure.dynamicmodulehelper.dynamicmoduleutility.registermodule%28v=VS.99%29.aspx) method from the `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` assembly:

```
public class Initializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(MyModule));
    }
}
```

the only thing left is to add the necessary attribute to your `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Initializer), "Initialize")]
```

Comment: Nice! I was having a problem where a custom HTTP error handler (loaded via web.config) was interfering with IIS warm-up processes. Loading the DLL seemed to be blocking the warm-up process from kicking off immediately and as a result I didn't see the remapManagedRequestsTo file load until the app had loaded, negating it's usefulness. Using this method to load the module seems to address the issue and the warm-up process is kicking off immediately.

Comment: It appears here in 2021 Microsoft has marked this method of registration as obsolete, and the new way is HttpApplication.RegisterModule() https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097973/176877