# How to programmatically remove an HttpModule from the ASP.NET pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

We can programatically add HttpModules using `DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (SomeHttpModule))` - is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Don't directly know of a way to do remove them programmetically. This post might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime. Isn't it better to check in your custom HttpModule if it should be applied to the current request or not?

Answer (score -1):

1. Instantiate the HTTP Module in `Init` method in `Global.asax`
2. Call `Module.Init(`) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime)
3. In `Init` method of your module, hook required eventhandlers.
4. Override the `Dispose` method in the handler and unhook the
   eventhandlers.
5. Expose the instance as public property on `global.asax` so that you
   can call `Dispose` when you want to unregister the module

   ```
   // Global.asax
   ```

public IHttpModule MyModuleInstance { get; private set; }

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    MyModuleInstance = new MyModule();
    MyModuleInstance.Init(this);
}



 // MyModule.cs
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.BeginRequest -= context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        _context = context;
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }
   private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        app.Context.Response.Write("Hello from OnBeginRequest in custom module.<br>");
    }
```

// TO unregister

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ApplicationInstance.MyModuleInstance.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: No, Dispose isn't going to work.  This is completely specific to an implementation of IHttpModule.  I want it removed from the pipeline in the same way DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule adds it to the pipeline.  Also, the reason I want to remove it is because it's added by default.  If I had the ability to add it to my application instance I would just *not* add it.

Comment: @Matt - that is strange. Why do you want to remove a module added by someone else? MOreover the DynamicModuleUtility says it is an infrastructure utility and is not intended to be used directly from your code. Do explain the scenario in more details in your question so that it helps people trying to answer.

Comment: Because if you use Razor with ASP.NET MVC 3 you load the FormsAuthentication module.