# HttpModules on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

Is it possible to do changes on the HttpModules list in the web.config when I execute a "Swap VIP" on Windows Azure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime

Comment: I changed my modules so they eventually jump the execution depending on the current host-header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a VIP swap, your instances do not receive any kind of notification, so I don't believe  this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you wouldn't be able to change an HTTP module would be:

- the HTTP Module updates the number of endpoints for your service

For more information on what you can do during a VIP swap or In-place upgrade view the [documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx)

Comment: I couldn´t find any reference to modules configuration in the link you have mentioned. Anyway, including or excluding a http module don´t take effect over the endpoints.

Comment: VIP Swap (in simplest of explanations) is simply replacing the DNS record of the Production domain and pointing it to your "Staging VM". Whatever is set up in that instance prior to swapping the VIP is what state it will be post swap. If you would like to add HTTP Modules during an inplace upgrade you would be able to do this because IIS would read the new web.config file and change accordingly.