# register httpmodule in web.config but my web.config is out side the root folder

Tags: httpmodule

if I register httpmodule in web.config it work but if I put my web.config out side the root folder it is not working.

```
<httpmodule>         
 <add name="HeaderModule"  type="AddHeader.HeaderModule,AddHeader"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: public static IHttpModule Module = new header();
        public override void Init()
        {
            base.Init();
            Module.Init(this);
        }

Comment: use this code globel.asax page

Answer (score 0):

While the following solution works it may not solve your problem. Since you can have multiple web.configs, why not create a web.config in your root whose sole purpose is to register the httpModule. All the other non-httpModule web.config stuff can be put in other web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to programmaitcally register the httpModule at runtime.

[Programmatically register HttpModules at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime?rq=1) (link from stack overflow, so don't ding me)