# NLog ${aspnet-request-posted-body} not returning data

Tags: nlog

Trying to log all API calls for an ASP.NET Web API 2 project. Created a `DelegatingHandler` and not able to get the `aspnet-request-posted-body` layout render to work.

**Type**: Bug (or maybe I'm missing something?)

**NLog version**: 5.0.1

**NLog.Web version**: 5.1.0

**NLog.Extensions.Logging version**: (not installed)

**Platform**: .Net 4.7.2 (working with a ASP.Net Web API 2)

**Current NLog config** (xml or C#, if relevant)

```xml
  <nlog autoReload="True"
        throwConfigExceptions="False"
        internalLogLevel="Trace"
        internalLogFile="${basedir}App_Data\Logs\internal-nlog.txt"
        xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="App_Data/Logs"/>
    <!-- enable ASP.NET layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets async="true">
      <target name="mainfile"
              xsi:type="File"
              fileName="${logDirectory}/main-${shortdate}.txt"
              layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-posted-body}" />
    </targets>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="mainfile" />
  </nlog>
```

- What is the current result?

```
  2022-07-27 17:19:21.5446|
```

- What is the expected result?

```
  2022-07-27 17:19:21.5446|{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}
```

- Did you checked the [Internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)?
  **Yes, the Internal Log had 0 (zero) errors**
- Please post full exception details (message, stacktrace, inner exceptions)
  **None**
- Are there any workarounds?
  **Not sure**
- Is there a version in which it did work?
  **Have not tried**
- Can you help us by writing an unit test?
  **Not sure how for this**

Code:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Api.Handlers {
    public class LogFilter : DelegatingHandler {
        private readonly NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
            if (request?.Content != null) {
                // Do stuff
            }

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response?.Content != null) {
                // Do stuff
            }
            
            _logger.Info("test");
            
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a breaking change in NLog.Web v5 where [${aspnet-request-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) was [removed](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/754) (because the implementation was not threadsafe).

Then with NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.1 it was [restored](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/781), but required that one replaced:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
   context.Request.EnableBuffering();
   await next();
});
```

With (If using ASP.NET Core):

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>();
```

Of if using ASP.NET MVC v4, then [register HTTP module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime) `NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyModule`.